# Continue list environment using normal list coding

Tags: lists

I am using normal `list` coding in `tablenotes` environment.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\TNmakelabel#1{%
  \gdef\@tempa{#1}%
  \ifx\@tempa\@empty%
  \else%
    \textsuperscript{#1}%
  \fi%
}%
\newenvironment{tablenotes}{%
  \vspace*{3pt}
  \list{}{%
    \topsep\z@%
    \partopsep\z@
    \itemsep\z@%
    \parsep\z@%
    \itemindent\z@%
    \setlength\leftmargin{\z@}%
    \setlength\labelwidth{\z@}%
    \setlength\labelsep{\z@}%
    \rightskip\z@%
    \leftskip\z@%
%    \let\textbf\tablefootboldfont%
%   \let\textit\tablefootfont%
    \let\makelabel\TNmakelabel%
%    \tablefont
\noindent\ignorespaces\unskip%
  }%
}{\endlist}%
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{tablenotes}
\item[a] Occupancy factor: 0.33333; 
\item[b] Occupancy factor: 0.66667; 
\item[c] Occupancy factor: 0.22227. 
\end{tablenotes}

\end{document}
```

My current output is:

```
a Occupancy factor: 0.33333;
b Occupancy factor: 0.66667;
c Occupancy factor: 0.22227.
```

But my required output is:

```
a Occupancy factor: 0.33333; b Occupancy factor: 0.66667; c Occupancy factor: 0.22227.
```

How to get the required output. Please advice

Comment: There are three packages which can do that. Why don't you use them?

Comment: @Bernard I am using \usepackage[inline]{enumitem} Package and achieve the required output.